# How do I wait for a task to complete before continuing main thread?

Tags: swift

Have been learning to code in Swift, and I am using playgrounds to try out different challenges - development environment id Xcode. My current challenge is to call an API to get a currency conversion and display the result in the terminal.

The problem I have is that I am able to print the result if I place a `print(information.result)` within the task, but the final code line `print(exchange_value)` prints `0.0` in the terminal. My assumption is that the task has not completed, and therefore the assignment of the value from the task has not completed.

Is there a simple way to wait for the task to complete before continuing the main thread of execution?

I also am getting a warning on the error catch in Xcode `Immutable value 'error' was never used; consider replacing with '_' or removing it` - not sure why?

Thanks in advance for any advice or pointers.

```
import Foundation

// MARK: - Information
struct Information: Codable {
    let success: Bool
    let query: Query
    let info: Info
    let date: String
    let result: Double
}

// MARK: - Info
struct Info: Codable {
    let timestamp: Int
    let rate: Double
}

// MARK: - Query
struct Query: Codable {
    let from, to: String
    let amount: Int
}

// MARK: - Code

// Placeholder for the final result returned from the call
let exchange_value: Double = 0.0

// Declare the decoder as a JSON decoder
let decoder = JSONDecoder()

// Set up the URL and the API call
let url = "https://api.apilayer.com/exchangerates_data/convert?to=AED&from=GBP&amount=1"
var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: url)!,timeoutInterval: Double.infinity)
request.httpMethod = "GET"
request.addValue("REAL KEY REMOVED HERE", forHTTPHeaderField: "apikey")

// Create the task to make the request and get the response
let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
    guard let data = data
    else
    {
        print(String(describing: error))
        return
    }
    do
    {
        // Decode the data retrived from the request
        let information = try decoder.decode(Information.self, from:data)
        
        // Extract the returned value for the exchange value form the data
        let exchange_value = information.result
    } catch let error {
        print("error")
    }

}

task.resume()

// Print the exchange value that was returned form the request
print(exchange_value)
```

Comment: Use async/await, https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2021/10132/

Comment: 1) The main thread should NEVER have to wait for other threads. When your data task will complete, just perform code in the main thread. DispatchQueue.main.async {}
2) This error warning happened because you print string "error". Delete quotation marks

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/wwdc21/10132

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When `print(exchange_value)` runs, the value hasn't arrived yet, so likely you will get 0.0 printed.

To solve this, you could use async-await approach, by simply changing the Code part to this

```
// MARK: - Code

let url = "https://api.apilayer.com/exchangerates_data/convert?to=AED&from=GBP&amount=1"
var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: url)!,timeoutInterval: Double.infinity)
request.httpMethod = "GET"
request.addValue("REAL KEY REMOVED HERE", forHTTPHeaderField: "apikey")

func getExchangeValue(from request: URLRequest) async -> Double? {
    do {
        let (data, _) = try await URLSession.shared.data(for: request)
        let information = try JSONDecoder().decode(Information.self, from: data)
        return information.result
    } catch let error {
        print(error)
        return nil
    }
}

Task {
    let exchange_value = await getExchangeValue(from: request)
    print(exchange_value ?? "something wrong")
}
```

or you could let the function throws and handle the error after

```
func getExchangeValue(from request: URLRequest) async throws -> Double {
    let (data, _) = try await URLSession.shared.data(for: request)
    let information = try JSONDecoder().decode(Information.self, from: data)
    return information.result
}

Task {
    do {
        let exchange_value = try await getExchangeValue(from: request)
        print(exchange_value)
    } catch {
        print(error)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the insight - makes sense now and really useful to see the exam ple.